# Reuse a1708 display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, recycle

I've been searching around if there is any control board for the a1708 display. I have a broken macbook pro laying around from where the cpu is broken. So I though maybe i can reuse the display as an external display. Do anyone know a compatible control board?

Comment: A1708 covers 5 years of Mac models. Your search would have to be more specific.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have a 2016 model so I searched for the 2016 models and by apple part number but without any success

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would very much doubt there would be sufficient call for a 3rd party driver board for a screen never usually seen outside of the mac it was designed for. I thin even for the slightest chance, on somewehere like aliexpress etc, you'd need to start from a part number for the screen, not a computer model.

Comment: I did some further research and i looked into the schematics of the macbook. Is saw that the display of the macbook uses edp thats embedded displayport. This is a standard protocol so i'm going to try to make a fitting cable so that the display fits a cheap aliexpress controller

Comment: @nandodavis How did it go? I'm facing the same issue.